# Сбросить семя идентификации после удаления записей в таблице MySQL + NEST.js

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm, nest.js

подскажите, как я могу решить проблему, что когда я удаляю всех пользователей из таблицы или даже несколько, то у меня начинается счет id не с первого, а продолжает повышаться от прошлого id? К примеру у меня было в таблице 20 юзеров, удаляю их.. И следующий созданный user получает id 21. Использую nest+mysql+typeorm

Comment: По всей видимости используется **auto increment** у поля ***id***, который в принципе не допускает повторение ***id***. Можно вручную обнулять **auto increment** командой **ALTER TABLE <имя таблицы> AUTO_INCREMENT=0**

Comment: А чем вам мешает нумерация не сначала ? после полного удаления из таблицы вы конечно можете сбросить нумерацию, как сказано выше. Но вообще в 99% случаев, если программе требуется какая то определенная нумерация в id, то это ошибка проектирования и надо пересмотреть подход что бы быть не завязанным на конкретные значения id, ибо они не предсказуемы